# ImmersiveModeConfirmation with Espresso 2.2.2

Tags: android, junit4, android-espresso, android-junit

Looks like some virtual devices on Google cloud test servers can't execute tests properly because of the Immersive mode confirmation popup (shown here: https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html) - is there a way to automatically close that popup with Espresso? Basically my code works in a local emulator, but not on Google cloud servers.
This is what's failing:

```
View v = activity.getWindow().getDecorView();
v.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem using a similar version of @paul-t. Once the emulator has been started run the next command:

```
adb shell settings put secure immersive_mode_confirmations confirmed
```

After that you can execute your Espresso tests.

Inspiration: http://sviatoslavdev.blogspot.com/2018/02/adb-setings-secure.html

Answer (score 0):

You can run these ADB commands right after the emulator has started:

```
adb shell settings put secure immersive_mode_confirmations your.package.com
adb reboot (required)
```

*immersive_mode_confirmations* is a comma separated list of packages that no longer need confirmation for immersive mode

Comment: Unfortunately, that command didn't work :( This dialog is really annoying.

Comment: This may work if you have a rooted device I believe.

Comment: In the above example, replace "your.package.com" with "confirmed".  Turns out Android doesn't want a list of packages.

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution. It's similar to Paul's answer but is by setting the permission programmatically before your tests run instead of using the ADB.
There is a LinkedIn Open Source library that does everything for you, from getting WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS permissions to changing the need for immersive confirmation dialog dynamically. 
After setting up the library, use the following line before your test starts:

```
TestButler.setImmersiveModeConfirmation(false);
```

For more details and setup instructions go [here](https://github.com/linkedin/test-butler).